# Number of combinations

Tags: c

How to go about getting the number of combination ( C(5,4) ) without using recursion in C? Is there any other method or inbuilt library to do this?

Comment: If you question is about how to handle large numbers in C, and not about factorials or recursion then you should change the question.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid recursion?

Comment: @SRKX There are good reasons to avoid recursion, it almost always introduces overhead (the exception being tail-recursion) and in some scenarios stack-overflow. Also, when computing factorial there is not even a benefit to it.

Comment: @eznme : I know. I was trying to see what *his* motivations were.

Comment: @SRKX understood

Answer (score 6):

You can avoid recursion and looping completely if an approximation is acceptable, you can use [Stirling's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) to approximate the answer.

[image: Stirling's Approximation]

**Example**

Option 1: Recursively or iteratively calculate factorial(n)

```
5! = 5x4x3x2 = 120
```

Option 2: Use Stirling's Approximation

```
5! ~ sqrt(2*pi*5) * (n/e)^n = sqrt(10*pi) * (5/2.718281828)^5 
                            = sqrt(31.41592654) *  (1.839397206)^5
                            = 5.604991216 * 21.05608437
                            = 118.019168 (close to 120)
```

(Note: ~ means approximately and e is [Euler's number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29) defined 2.718281828)

This may seem silly because 5! is so small, but for a number like 100! the approximation works fairly well.

**Large example, n = 100:**

according to Google :

`100! = 9.33262154 × 10^157`

using Stirling's Approximation:

`100! = 9.3224838328837612788449900430478 x 10^157`

That's close enough for me :)

Comment: Your suggestion is good. The expected error is 1/12n of n! according to page 590 in http://books.google.ca/books?id=fUvv3zlzA2YC&pg=PA589&dq=calculate+factorial+for+large+number&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ixs6T5KOEMjRhAfppKmRCg&ved=0CE0Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=calculate%20factorial%20for%20large%20number&f=false

Answer (score 4):

What is wrong with using the formula:

`n!/(k! (n-k)!)`.

You don't need recursion to calculate a factorial.

Comment: but how to work with number such as 100!?

Comment: Then you need to use a library that supports a big integer, but you can still use the same formula.

Comment: Or, if an an approximate answer is ok, you can use the gamma function. For historical reasons in the 'C' runtime this function is called  tgamma (think 'true gamma'). tgamma(n) ~ (n-1)!, but the argument and return values are doubles, so you can accommodate quite large number.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate **factorial** for large numbers you can use a biginteger-library or arbitrary-precision library like http://gmplib.org/ or do it yourself (arbitrary-precision multiplication is easy, division not so) by using an array of unsigned ints.

Since you dont want to do it recursively, just iterate through the numbers from 1 to n, multiplying each of them into an biginteger you initialize with 1.

Then to calculate the number of **combinations not permutations** you calculate n!/k!/(n-k)!

Comment: Even with a big integer type you don't need to do all the n!, k! and (n-k)! calculations, you can simplify the fractional expression and remove redundant calculations, for example: `100!/(25!*75!) = (76*77*...*100)/25!` and further reduce it to `(100*99*98*97)/25*(96*95*94*93)/24...`

Answer (score 0):

Optimize the combination formula. If \binom{n}{r} is asked, first set r to be (r) or (n-r), whichever is smaller. Now use the normal shortcut method for finding combinations without calculating full factorials:

(n)(n-1)....(n-r+1)[r terms]/r!

Use [Stirling's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) if the numbers are too large. You don't have to use recursion, for loops are more efficient (though less aesthetically pleasing) for factorials and continued products.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you can construct a simple function to calculate n! = nx(n-1)x(n-2)x...x1.
Now for large numbers, you may need to divide your algorithm as follows:

part1: when the input number has an acceptable value to be used with the formula above. I am not a C developer, so I can't tell you what is this value, for now we'll call it (L). For this case, you simply apply the above formula.

part2: When the input number is greater than the acceptable value L:The formula c(n,k) = nx(n-1)x(n-2)x....x(n-k)!/((n-k)!*k!) this can be simplified as:

c(n,k)=nx(n-1)x(n-2)x....x(n-k+1)/k! (see [Related Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104914/unique-permutations-of-a-stringword/104929#104929))

this last equation involves smaller values than those in the original expression.

if k! in the above expression is less than or equal to L, then use the regular formula.

if k! > L or if nx(n-)x...x(n-k+1) > L you can use Sterling's formula as suggested by @Hunter McMillen